# тег <hr> выходит за пределы

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

тег hr выходит за пределы картинки (картинка добавлена через `background-image`) 
 css:

```
hr {
    position: absolute;
    top:auto;
    top: 90%;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;}
```

html:

```
<body>
    <header class="hd">
        <center>
            <hr>
            <a class="down" href="#down_"><h1>∨</h1></a>
        </center> 
    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Можете полностью код дать с html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас для `hr` задано свойство `position: absolute`, это значит, что `hr` находится вне потока, на его размеры не действуют другие элементы, кроме элемента c `position: relative` выше по вложенности. Если вы такое свойство не давали никакому элементу, значит размеры `hr`, в частности `width: 100%`  зависят от элемента `body`.

Если вы хотите, чтобы `hr` не вылезал за пределы фона какого-то элемента (вы не указали какого, возможно это `header`?), вам нужно задать для `header` свойство `position: relative`, не забыв скорректировать свойство `top` у элемента `hr`.

Так же возможным решением будет свойство `box-sizing: border-box` для элемента `hr`. Из вашего кода и скриншота почти ничего не возможно понять.